# asp.net devexpress works slow on firefox ang chrome but fast on ie

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, devexpress

Just like in title. It works much faster on IE (8, 9) than on firefox and chrome ?

How is it possible ?

Whats more I had to disable cookies on aspxGridViews because I had bad requests all the time,
thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is known to be the slowest browser among others and I have no clue on how this can be.  I would suggest that you post an example of this behavior in the [support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center/) for the investigation.